# How do i drop these unwanted levels from my variable

Tags: r

Basically ctb2 is city tax band a variable in data set, i just renamed it to make it easier for me, i have produced a summary and a table for the ctb2 as a starter like my advisor says, who also said i need to remove the Us from the variable since they are unknowns so i can just have the levels A to I as they are more relevant to my analysis
she also said i could replace them by NAs of which i have no idea how to do that as well been struggling to remove the U from the variable as I have no idea how
I need to keep just A to I and get rid of the U and the 952 just standing there. 
Im quite new to R and been researching on how but nothing make sense.
Please help

```
> summary(ctb2)
        A      B      C      D      E      F      G      H      I      U 
952  72258  75890 116903 104229  83516  49943  50607   5689    131  35020
```

Comment: Can you include a bit more about your problem?  maybe the line that generated `ctb2` and `dput(ctb2)` so we can reproduce this.  FWIW, it looks like the `952` is the row name like and that is just part of the way the R console displays.  I'd also suggest looking through any one of the excellent R Intros out there on the web.

Comment: i have reedited the question let me know if this helps?

Comment: @Justin the `952` isn't a row name, it's a count of empty (or perhaps " ") entries in `ctb2`.

Comment: In addition, since `ctb2` seems to have hundreds of thousands of entries, giving us `dput(ctb2)` probably wouldn't be terribly helpful...

Comment: Fair, but a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) lets us know a lot more about the specifics of the problem.  It also, in my experience, often leads to finding a solution or at least a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
ctb2[ctb2=="U"] <- NA
```

Since you also seem to have empty entries, you might want to do

```
ctb2[ctb2==""] <- NA
```

or

```
ctb2[ctb2==" "] <- NA
```

depending on what exactly that 952 is counting there.